# sql: get count of slightly modified query along with the sql select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have images table with following columns:- 1) imageId, 2) productId, 3)isApproved [flag 1/0]. One product can have multiple images.

We have stored procedure that has to return all approved images of a particular productId + count of all images (approved/non-approved) of that productId.

```
select * from images where isApproved=1
where productId = {user_entered_id};

select count(*) from images
where productId = {user_entered_id};
```

Is there any better way to get this 2 information from images table in just 1 query? It's a huge table and we want to minimize the SQL queries as much as possible.

One workaround is- to modify query1 and return all images to application server and filter isApproved=1 images there BUT it returns back isApproved=0 images to the application server which is unnecessary and risky. Any better way?

Comment: Maybe
`select count(*) AS total, sum(isApproved) AS approved
from images where productId=id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate the values:

```
select group_concat(case when isApproved = 1 then image_id end) as approved_image_ids,
       count(*) as num_images
from images i
where productId = {user_entered_id};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing it. But the count will be repeated several times (depending on the number of instances with product id as "user-input").

```
SELECT imageId, count from
Images NATURAL JOIN
(SELECT productId, count(*) as count from images where isApproved=1 
GROUP BY productId 
HAVING productId = <user_input>)
WHERE productId = <user_input>;
```

The GROUP BY clause can be skipped however.
Hope this helps.